# Usage, usage… que peux-tu donc bien signifier ?

Tags: discussion, tags

Quelqu'un peut-il me dire ce que les questions regroupées sous le tag [usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) ont en commun? Je me demande si ce tag a vraiment un intérêt, ou si l'on doit le supprimer.

Dans l'attente d'une éventuelle décision, quelle serait la description wiki qui lui conviendrait le mieux ?

Answer (score 3):

Contrairement à ce que suggère le wiki je le vois comme « Ces deux expressions semblent convenir pour dire ce truc, laquelle est la mieux/plus uitilisée ».

Comment: Wow, je suis très surpris de constater qu'il y a du vrai dans cette réponse. Reste à voir combien de questions ne correspondent pas à cette description.

Comment: Hmm, je note aussi que dans ce cas la différence avec *choix-de-mot* paraît très subtile.

Comment: Juste. Visiblement *usage* ⊊ *choix-de-mots* pour cet emploi.

Answer (score 1):

Nous sommes partis des étiquettes du site [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). L'intérêt de l'étiquette [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/usage) y est [débattu](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30/does-the-usage-tag-have-any-value) depuis longtemps.

Je comprends [usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) comme ce qui n'est pas couvert par des règles (par opposition à la grammaire ou au vocabulaire, par exemple). C'est un peu flou et très général, donc je ne suis pas foncièrement opposé à ce qu'on demande la suppression de cette étiquette. D'un autre côté, je ne suis pas convaincu qu'elle soit vraiment mauvaise. Il faudrait peut-être affiner sa description et son usage.

Notez que si on la supprime, ce sera suite à une décision suffisamment consensuelle sur Méta, et ce sera fait par le personnel de Stack Exchange. On ne va pas éditer 87 questions pour supprimer l'étiquette.

Comment: C'est comme ça qu'elle était pensée, mais visiblement pas comme ça qu'elle est utilisée.