# Synonymizing “usage-de-mots” and “usage” tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Would there be any reason to keep separate tags [usage-de-mots](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage-de-mots) and [usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage)? I can't see any difference in meaning.

(The *usage* tag is already vague and difficult enough to figure out on its own… [Usage, usage… que peux-tu donc bien signifier ?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/usage-usage-que-peux-tudonc-bien-signifier))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that [usage-de-mots](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage-de-mots) questions should be retagged to either [choix-de-mot](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/choix-de-mot), [usage](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage) or [sens](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sens) as *usage de mots* could be any of those three. I fail to see any other point to [usage-de-mots](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage-de-mots).

And now it is done.